# How can I invoke two separate controls on the same form asynchronously from two separate async functions?

Tags: c#, events, async-await, delegates, invoke

I'm working on a software in C# for stocks and charts. I have a class "Stock" that has a list of class "Candles". The Stock class receives a candle from online exchange with 4 decimal properties open, high, low, and close. The Stock class creates a candle and updates its properties. It also updates the current price of the stock. Then it raises two events when properties change. one event for candle changed, and another event for price changed.

When the events are raised, I have a form "Details" which should update a candlestick chart and also a price label.

The data comes in every few milliseconds, but for a reason that I can't understand only the chart updates while the price label stays frozen. If I pause disable the events that updates the chart then the price label updates. Why the two controls doesn't update at the same time?

This is the code:

```cs
private decimal _currentPrice { get; set; }

public decimal currentPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPrice;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != _currentPrice)
                {
                    _currentPrice = value;
                    OnPriceChanged(value);
                }
                   
            }
        }

public event Action<decimal> PriceChanged;
public event Action<Candles> LastCandleChanged;

protected virtual void OnPriceChanged(decimal price)
        {
            
            if (PriceChanged != null)
            {
                    
                
                PriceChanged(price);
            }
            
        }

protected virtual void OnLastCandleChanged(Candles candle)
        {
            
            if (LastCandleChanged != null)
            {
                
                LastCandleChanged(candle);

            }
            
        }
```

When I update all the prices of open, high, low, and close I call the following:

```cs
OnLastCandleChanged(candle);

public event System.EventHandler<Candles> LastCandleChanged;
protected virtual void OnLastCandleChanged(Candles candle) {
            if (LastCandleChanged != null) {
                LastCandleChanged(this, candle);
            }
}
```

On a form called "DetailsForm" I have two event listeners created when the form loads. They call the update functions.

```cs
stock.PriceChanged += async (sender1, args) => await updatePrice(sender1, args);
stock.LastCandleChanged += async (sender2, args) => await updateLastCandle(sender2, args);

public async Task updatePrice(object sender, decimal price) {
            if (this.Visible) // to avoid invoking when form is closed
            {
                await Task.Run(() => {
                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                         priceLbl.Text = price.ToString();
                    }));
                });
            }
        }

public async Task updateLastCandle(object sender, Candles candle) {
            if (this.Visible) // to avoid invoking when form is closed
            {
                await Task.Run(() => {
                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                        updateChart(candle);
                    }));
                });
            }
        }
```

Why don't the two controls update at the same time?

The code for updating the Chart:

```
public void updateChart(Candles candle){

//these 4 variables are declared in class level
close = candle.close;
open = candle.open;
high = candle.high;
low = candle.low;

if (candle == lastCandle)
{
  detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points.RemoveAt(xPoint);

  if (candle.close > candle.open)
  {
                    
   detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points.AddXY(xPoint, low, high, 
   open, close);
                                            
                    
   detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points[xPoint].Color = 
   Color.PaleGreen;
                    
   }
   else
   {
                    
   detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points.AddXY(xPoint, low, high, 
   close, open);

                    
   detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points[xPoint].Color = 
   Color.LightPink;

    }
}
else if (candle.index > lastCandle.index)
{

  lastCandle = candle;
  xPoint++;

  if (candle.close > candle.open)
  {
                    
     detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points.AddXY(xPoint, low, 
     high, open, close);

                    
      detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points[xPoint].Color = 
      Color.PaleGreen;


  }
  else
  {
                    
       detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points.AddXY(xPoint, low, 
       high, close, open);

                    
       detailedChart.Series["Candles2"].Points[xPoint].Color = 
       Color.LightPink;

   }



   //update scale


                
   detailedChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum += 1;
                
   detailedChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum += 1;
                
   detailedChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].RecalculateAxesScale();

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Try adding better tags, it is not clear what is your UI? Webform, Winform? WPF?...

Comment: WinForm application

Comment: The code is overly complicated and with unnecessary context changes and marshalling. What's the implementation of  the`updateChart` method?

Comment: The updateChart method examines the last Candle in List<Candles> in Stock class. The candle object includes open, high, low, and close prices. If the candle was updated then it removes the last candle at X axis-Point and creates a new chart candle then adds it to the chart. I didn't include it because it's too long and complicated and I didn't think it is relevant.

Comment: Paulo. Please explain what did you mean unnecessary context changes and marshalling? I'm open to learn from all suggestions.

Comment: I edited the question and added the initial code that trigger the events.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to say why that's happening from the code you've shown, but there is some "code smell": some things that look odd that may or may not be contributing.

For example:

```
stock.PriceChanged += async (sender1, args) => await updatePrice(sender1, args);
stock.LastCandleChanged += async (sender2, args) => await updateLastCandle(sender2, args);
```

In these lines, you're creating an `async void` anonymous method (with `async (sender1, args)`) to call a single async method. That adds one method to the call stack unnecessarily, but along with it all the computation required to make an extra async method work. You're better off just declaring those event handler methods as `async void` (the only acceptable use of `async void` is for event handlers) and use them directly.

Then there is also this, which is the "unnecessary context changes and marshalling" that Paulo is talking about in the comment:

```
await Task.Run(() => {
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
         priceLbl.Text = price.ToString();
    }));
});
```

Calling [`Task.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) tells it to run the code in a different thread, but then you immediately use `BeginInvoke()` to tell it to run the code in the UI thread. So both of those calls become useless because you end up back on the same thread you started from (the UI thread).

Applying those two suggestions, you'd end up with this:

```
stock.PriceChanged += updatePrice;
stock.LastCandleChanged += updateLastCandle;

public async void updatePrice(object sender, decimal price) {
    if (this.Visible) // to avoid invoking when form is closed
    {
         priceLbl.Text = price.ToString();
    }
}

public async void updateLastCandle(object sender, Candles candle) {
    if (this.Visible) // to avoid invoking when form is closed
    {
        updateChart();
    }
}
```

And the reason Paulo asked for the implementation of `updateChart()` is because it could be something in there that is preventing the text price from updating, since you say that the text stops updating when the chart is updating.

Comment: Gabriel. Thank you for your answer. I added the code for updating the chart in the original question. 1. If I remove "BeginInvoke" I get an error because the call is generated from a different thread so I get a cross thread exception. 2. I tested the code you suggested but it generated errors because the async functions (updateLastCandle...) are not awaited. The update chart function tries to work on the same index (x axis) while previous async function still updating that index, so I get "index out of range errors".  If I remove async completely the whole form becomes frozen.

Comment: *"1. If I remove "BeginInvoke" I get an error because the call is generated from a different thread"* - Right, that's why you need to remove the `Task.Run()` too.

Comment: *"2. I tested the code you suggested but it generated errors because the async functions (updateLastCandle...) are not awaited."* - On which line do you see that error?